# Unicorn error: text file busy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I start my unicorn server using the following command `bundle exec unicorn -E production -c config/unicorn.rb`

but I find the server isn't running. I check the log and find an error occurs:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0-turbo/gems/unicorn-4.2.1/lib/unicorn/
    http_serv‌​er.rb:202:in rename': Text file busy - (/vagrant/ruby-china
    /tmp/pids/0.2628933382622929.13474, /vagrant/ruby-china/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid)
    (Errno::ETXTBSY)
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved this problem, and the matter is I am using virtual box and deploying the project in sync folders. So I try to move the folder to local file system, and the error is gone. May it help somebody.

Comment: This solved the problem for me too. I'm using a Vagrant VM on a Windows 8 host.